# Nodejs - Get the instance_url from salesforce oauth response in Amazon Alexa skill or an API to get the instance_url

Tags: salesforce, alexa-skills-kit

I have developed a simple alexa skill using nodejs which uses salesforce and have been successful linking the account(oauth 2.0). However what i want to do is to invoke any salesforce API and for this i require the **instance_url**  that is returned in the oauth response. How do access this in alexa skill? Or is their any salesforce api through which i can get the instance url using the accessToken?

Comment: Appears you need to use the URL CLass within the Salesforce REST API. There is some information at: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64616/how-to-get-salesforce-instance-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** : I got an API from salesforce that returns the Information about a User.

API Endpoint : `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo`

I got the solution from this [stackexchange link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/104891/47499).
The API accepts an access token in header or as a parameter 'oauth_token'. Refer the above link or this [salesforce help link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_using_userinfo_endpoint.htm&type=0).